# How to allow traffic to app engine access from compute engines of different project.

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

On google cloud I have created an app engine on one project and have some auto scaled(server spinup/spindown according to traffic) compute engines on different project. I have a task for allowing traffic to app engine only from those auto scaled compute engines. 
Problem with the auto scaled environment we can't guess the server public IP, where as we can get private subnet IP's.

Please let me know how can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For connecting through a private IP, you need your app engine and compute engine instances  to be in the same network. App Engine standard environment is on a different network than the Compute Engine instances and don't have private IP access to each other currently.
You can't achieve that with app engine standard, you will need to consider app engine flex for this (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#network_settings) how to set the network of your app engine flex instances).

You will have to connect using the external IP address of the service running on your Compute Engine instance by [setting up your firewalls](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/creating-firewalls).

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by doing as follow:
Let's say you have Project A and Project B, and a service running in Project A that wants to connect to a compute engine running in Project B.

- You need two VPC in A and B with no IP collision.
- Create a VPC Network peering From A to B and from B to A.
- Create a VPC serverless access connector in project A.
- Config your service to use the new connector.

vpc_access_connector:
  name: "projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/REGION/connectors/CONNECTOR_NAME"